# One to many relationship with a table of fixed number of objects

Tags: aws-amplify

I need to create a relationship between two entities basically something like content -> categories.

i.e. I have a limited number of category entries and content objects are related to one or more categories.

It looks like Amplify currently is set up to have unique entries in the category table for each content object. That's obviously not ideal in this situation. Also, I don't want to delete the category(ies) when I delete the content object

What's the best way to solve for this?